# Return code for insert sql in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I have a bulk data which I'm planning to upload using simple SQL insert in Sybase.
Now some of the sql's fail due to some constraint violation.

Since I run all the sqls in one go, I can't find which sql has failed.

The DB client console is just prints this,

```
Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object 'Employee' with unique index 'Employee_uk'
(0 rows affected)
```

So I was thinking of having a INT to capture each insert statement's execution and print if they have failed.

I found this for a procedure but I can't seem to find a way to do it for a SQL,

```
DECLARE @status INT
EXECUTE @status = proc_sample
IF @status != 0
    PRINT 'procedure failed'
```

Is there a way to get the return code for an insert? Or any other ways?

Note: I don't want to have a BEGIN and END for each sql as it takes so long  and I can't afford that.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check @@error directly after the INSERT statement (which I assume you are executing). If it is not 0, then you just had an error condition. However, the error checking must be imemdiately aftr the INSERT. *Any* other statement executed will wipe out the error status. Best copy @error first:

```
DECLARE @err INT
[...]
INSERT INTO mytable....
SET @err = @@ERROR
IF @err <> 0
BEGIN
... error action...
END
```